# How to create dynamic UItextfields in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a view which has set to dynamic text fields. From my API a JSON object is passed to the view based on JSON object values, text fields should be dynamically shown. Im using storyboard and not programmatically creating views.

```
json = [{"sydneyTomelbourn":500$},
        {"sydneyToHampshre":100$},
        {"sydneyToUSA":200$}
       ]
```

These prices are editable. and that should display on text fields.
Is there any suggestion for this?

Comment: you can use tableView

Comment: create custom cell uitableview

Comment: in a for loop, keep on adding textfields, the textfields top will always be calculated as i*(some constant) and keep that tag as i

Comment: @JaydeepVyas ya that's right.

Comment: @Jaydeep@サンディープ Thanks for the reply this is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is very easy just create custom cell class to achive this

> STEP:1 create array of json response

say arrayForPrice which holds all the price in given json

> STEP:2 create custom class for tableViewCell

```
class InputDataCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var txtItemPrice: UITextField!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

> STEP:3 assign price from array to uitextFieald in cellForRowMethod
>   like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let inputDataCell:InputDataCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inputItemCell", for: indexPath) as? InputDataCell)! //InputDataCell is the Custom class For uitableViewCell

                inputDataCell.txtItemPrice.text = arrayForPrice[indexPath.row]

        return inputDataCell
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The way of achieving this is correct. Maybe codes are not full, but way to achieve is right